# how can I create json data structure in mongodb like this?

Tags: arrays, json, django, mongodb, djongo

I am having a problem to create this structure inside my mongodb. I'm using django. Djongo is the model i used to try and create this but I cant seem to find a way. I've tried using Arrayfield and embeddedfield as well but I'm stuck.

[image]

[image]